# Wildcard SSL certificates for multiple subdomain

Tags: apache, ubuntu, https, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I have a system with multiple clients. Each client has their own subdomain.

```
client1.example.com
client2.example.com
...
```

**At the server side, all requests are redirected to `*.example.com`.** Then my business logic reads the subdomain (like `client1`) and gives response to the client accordingly.

So basically, I **do not** configure each subdomain on the server. I just add it to my database and my code handles it properly.

I am trying to apply wildcard SSL certificates to all these subdomains. Also, I want all future clients to automatically get `https`.

But I don't know how to configure this. I have tried using `Let's Encrypt`, but no luck. The actual domain `example.com` gets `https` but not the client domains.

Any help with configuration would be really helpful.
Or, may be, this setup is just not possible. I don't know.

Please help.

P.S. `example.com` is just a dummy domain I am referring to.

P.P.S. I use apache2 web server on Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Comment: You need a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com` IN ADDITION to `example.com` (could be in same certificate or two separate ones)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I tried that. It did not work. I am getting self-signed certificates for `client1` and `client2`. Of course, I could have goofed up while configuring. So I'll try it again. I just want to know whether this is possible? Because, I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is possible. I now have a certificate in place for `*.example.com` and it works on all my arbitrary subdomains, viz.,

```
client1.example.com
client2.example.com
...
```

I followed these steps:

```
$ wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
$ chmod a+x ./certbot-auto

$ sudo ./certbot-auto certonly \
--server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory \
--manual --preferred-challenges dns \
-d *.example.com
```

Then using the files created at `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/`, I updated the values from my control panel (I use `Vestacp`)

```
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
^ Copy contents into “SSL Certificate” field.

cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
^ Copy contents into “SSL Key” field.

cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
^ Copy contents into “SSL CA / Intermediate” field.
```

Make changes according to your control panel.

Follow [this article](https://www.codementor.io/@sandesh87/1ec7bbpged) for detailed steps and explanation.